# Selenium: different behaviour between driver.implicitly_wait() and time.sleep()

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to **scrape** a website with Selenium (as it is a website with a dynamically loaded content).

However, to wait for such a dynamic content to be loaded, while I usually use `time.sleep()`, I have just known about (and tried) `driver.implicitly_wait()` but it seems I do not get the expected content.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'

baseSite = 'https://bair.berkeley.edu/students.html'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver.implicitly_wait(5) --> full content is not retrieved
driver.get(baseSite)

time.sleep(5) # full content is retrieved

source = driver.page_source
print(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

The setting of an implicit wait timeout (i.e., using `implicitly_wait()` does not affect how the browser loads a page. What that method does is poll the DOM for the desired element when using `find_element` or `find_elements`. In the code you posted, setting the implicit wait timeout has no effect because you are not attempting to find any elements on the page.

If you were to provide more details about what you’re expecting (aside from saying, “I want the page to be ‘fully loaded’”, because that phrase is so vague as to be meaningless), it might be easier to provide more guidance.

Comment: Let's say, for example, my goal is to retrieve all people listed in the page. Each person's data are within a `2u student-entry` div element. Some people are statically loaded in the page (hope my vocabulary is right) while others are dynamically retrieved by means of (Ajax?) request to a Firebase backend. I want to wait for all these `2u student-entry` without making any extra assumption.

Comment: @floflo29 You've still not provided enough to go on. There is no way to know _a priori_ when all of those are located "without making any extra assumption." You'll need to know what signals to the page that all of the entries are completely retrieved from the backend. Absent that, you have no way to avoid a race condition, which you might lose, no matter how long your static sleep is. You have some options for detecting that the retrieval has finished, but it will require some knowledge of the structure of the page and its internal workings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an explicit wait, which would wait until a certain condition is met. For example,

`element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))`

would wait until the WebDriver located that element (until 10 seconds have passed, at which point, it would time out). This link is helpful for learning more about different types of waits in Selenium. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html